# Polar representation from x,y in Java

Tags: java, math

I am building the following:

```
public class Point2
{
    private double _radius , _alpha;    

    public Point2 ( int x , int y )
    {
        _radius = Math.sqrt ( Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow (y,2) ) ;
        _alpha = Math.atan(y/x) ;
    }

}
```

The only thing that stuck me is the _alpha calc.
I'm trying to think how to operate this one using Math class the shortest and **readable** way...
Is my way OK ?
thnx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java but for sure just use [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

```
_alpha = Math.atan2(y,x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr E is correct, atan2 seems to be the way to go. Here is the link to the appropriate [javadoc for atan2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29).